# focus textbox only if value is empty

Tags: forms, html, textbox, focus, autofocus

I'm currently using the html5 autofocus for a login form. I am looking for a function that will autofocus the username textbox only if empty, and if not empty to autofocus on the next textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the HTML below

```
<input name="username" value="a" autofocus="autofocus">
<input name="password" type="password">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You can do something like this with jQuery

```
var $username = $('[name="username"]');
var $password = $('[name="password"]');
if($username.val()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.trim().length > 0){
    $password.focus();
}​
```

Should be that simple. Make sure Javascript is at the bottom of the page or you can use $(document).ready() function to make sure Javascript is run after HTML is rendered.

---

More details based on additional information

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" autofocus="true" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

The reason it doesn't work for your case is because you don't have an attribute called "name". I think you probably should read a little bit about [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to understand why. If you use ID, then this is how you would do it.

```
var $username = $('#UserName');
var $password = $('#password');
if($username.val()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.trim().length > 0){
    $password.focus();
}​
```

Of course you now have to match the selector for password so it will actually select password input to set the focus on.

Comment: Your example works for input boxes, but when trying to use it with an asp textbox it doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Show some example so I can give you matching answer.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" autofocus="true" required="true"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 1):

Searches the page for input fields, and forces the focus on the first empty one. We might want to restrict the fields to a given form, and possibly add textareas as well - I'll leave that up yo you though - nothing too hard.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    i = -1, I = inputs.length,
    curr;

for (; ++i < I;) {
    curr = inputs[i];
    if ( !curr.value.length ) {
        curr.focus();
        break;
    }
}​
```